# Initializing MLUpdateTask causes signal SIGABRT: Error loading file: *.mlmodelc/model.espresso.weights

Tags: ios, swift, keras, xcode11, coreml

(I'm new to ML, so please excuse me in case I'm talking/doing bullshit...)

### What I was trying to do:

I was trying to create an app for exploring ML (in order to get into SwiftUI and CoreML). The app is all about teaching some kind of neuronal network to play tic-tac-toe using reinforcement learning. In order to do so, you can have the `AIPlayer` play against a `RandomPlayer`, an `AlgorithmicPlayer`, itself or yourself. The `AIPlayer` is supposed to learn form every game it played by updating the underlying model using the game's outcome and the picks it made during the game.

### The problem

The problem is, that initializing the `MLUpdateTask` fails after a specific amount of updates with a signal SIGABRT. Thus, the app crashes. The exact amount depends on the device. When running it on my iPhone 6s, the 240th initialization of `MLUpdateTask` fails, on the Simulator, it's the 243rd one.

The error message I get:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: Error loading file: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/714E7417-B792-4F80-8EAE-A2855E138A95/TicTacToe.app/UpdatableNNClassifier.mlmodelc/model.espresso.weights
```

I traced the error down to that line...the whole code is on GitHub. 
https://github.com/theMomax/TicTacToe/blob/0182db0af27498d504fb5dcfd0556267e23c063b/TicTacToe/MLBase.swift#L132

### What I tried to solve the problem:

I tried to reduce the amount of layers in my model. No effect.

I tried to only have one update task at a time. No effect.

I ported the whole app over to macOS. That "solved" the problem.

### Model

[This](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/blob/master/examples/updatable_models/updatable_mnist.ipynb) notebook is the basis for [the one I used to produce the CoreML Model](https://github.com/theMomax/TicTacToe/blob/master/MLModel/UpdatableNNClassifier.ipynb). I only changed what was necessary to adapt the model to my I/O formats. Probably the model I have right now won't be able to actually learn/get better, because of its structure, but I don't think that's relevant right now.

### System

Mac: 10.15 Beta (19A582a)

iPhone: 13.1.2 (17A860)

Xcode: 11.1 (11A1027)

### Updating Code

[Here](https://github.com/theMomax/TicTacToe/blob/master/TicTacToe/MLBase.swift) is the file on GitHub. My reference here is [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/704/) from WWDC. I tried to remove the unnecessary parts below and add some comments describing when each function is called...

```
// is initialized once on startup
class MLWrapper {

    let bundle = Bundle(for: UpdatableNNClassifier.self)

    let updatableModelURL: URL

    var model = UpdatableNNClassifier()

    var trainingData: [(gameboard: [Position: FieldState], pick: Position)] = []

    init() {
        self.updatableModelURL = bundle.url(forResource: "UpdatableNNClassifier", withExtension: "mlmodelc")!
    }

    // Returns a randomly selected alternative to pick. 
    private func other(than pick: Position, in gameboard: [Position: FieldState?]) -> Position? {
        // ...
    }

    private func convertInput(gameboard: [Position: FieldState]) -> MLMultiArray {
        // ...
    }

    private func convertOutput(output: UpdatableNNClassifierOutput) -> Position? {
        // ...
    }

    // is called each time the `AIPlayer` is supposed to make a pick
    func predict(on gameboard: [Position: FieldState]) -> Position? {
        let input = convertInput(gameboard: gameboard)
        if let output = try? model.prediction(gameboard: input) {
            if let result = convertOutput(output: output) {

                // record input and output, so that it can be used to train
                // train the model, when the game's outcome is known
                trainingData.append((gameboard, result))
                return result
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        } else {
            print("Unexpected runtime error in \(model).")
            return nil
        }
    }

    // is called after a game is completed
    func reflect(on outcome: Outcome) {
        do {            
            let bp: MLBatchProvider = try MLArrayBatchProvider(dictionary: ["gameboard": trainingData.compactMap { i in
                return convertInput(gameboard: i.gameboard)
            }, "pick": trainingData.compactMap({ I in

                // in case the `AIPlayer` won or achieved a draw, its pick was good, otherwise, try any other pick next time
                outcome != .defeat ? i.pick.description() : other(than: i.pick, in: i.gameboard)?.description() ?? i.pick.description()
            })])
            // reset trainingData
            trainingData = []            

            // the line below is the one that fails
            let updateTask = try MLUpdateTask(forModelAt: updatableModelURL, trainingData: bp, configuration: self.model.model.configuration, completionHandler: { ctx in
                if ctx.task.error == nil {
                    self.model.model = ctx.model
                } else {
                    print(ctx.task.error!)
                }
            })

            updateTask.resume()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

### The question

So, my basic question is: Is there something wrong with my updating code? Or is this most likely a beta-bug? Do you have any suggestions on what I could try to solve this?

All of that code above is called from a DispatchQueue in `Controller.swift`. Could that be a problem?